# ng-repeat set selected value if object has that property

Tags: angularjs

I am still learning Angular, but this keeps me bugging: how can I get selected value in dropdown combobox when giving item property in textbox?
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gXq6BZMk67qnYk7baAaC?p=preview)

I would be thankful if anyone could help me with this

```
    <pre>
    AssetCode:
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Kods" ng-model="assetcode" on-enter="add()">
    <div ng-show="pers_select.chpers">
    Person in charge:
    <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="pers_select.takepers" data-ng-options="a.name for a in persons"></select>
    </div>
    </pre>
```

I dont know how to put html here in order to see it, but in plunker I hope you will see it fine :)

```
       $scope.$watch('pers_select', function() {
       console.log($scope.pers_select.takepers);
       if ($scope.pers_select.chpers === true && $scope.pers_select.takepers === null) {
       for (var i in $scope.assets) {
       if ($scope.assets[i].person !== null) {
         $scope.pers_select.takepers = $scope.assets[i].person;
         //somehow assign person value from record to combobox, as selected value
       } else {

       }
     }
   }
 }, true);
 });
```

UPDATE:
I gave part of code so it isnt clear what I do there, I guess. So when i select in combobox (isnt shown in plunker) parameters records are selected in table, where are those asset properties which needs to be checked. When with code reader reads its ID then it is pasted in AssetCode textbox and pressed enter. Then combobox appears where I can assign or delete person in charge of asset, but what I need to be done is that, when that combobox(person) appears selected value in it is the one of that assets person in charge (if it has one).

More clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your requirement correctly, you want to, for example enter John in the input box and it automatically selects John in the select box. I hope this is correct, it was not quite clear to me.

First thing is that your `add()` function should also include which it is you want to add:

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Kods" ng-model="assetcode" on-enter="add(assetcode)">
```

So now you have the user name, but in your select model you use an object, based on your `$scope.persons` array. So we have to filter out the correct object we want to get and as the name suggests, thats what `$filter` is for. You have to inject it into your controller first.

```
 $scope.add = function(person){
   $scope.pers_select.chpers = true; //In input(Other field) this is defined as true
   var personObj = $filter('filter')($scope.persons, {name: person});
   $scope.pers_select.takepers = personObj[0];
 };
```

See this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/T5kdx28OFVKNRMitxuwh?p=preview

I did not quite get what you want to achieve in the `watch` function of `pers_select`, but to me the whole procedure looks rather unnecessary.

Comment: You did answer my question. I will update question in order to explain.

Comment: If it in fact solved your problem please think about accepting it as the answer. If there are still issues remaining or it was not to the point I am happy to help.

Comment: I tried to put in this function, but then realised it isnt actually what I needed, but in that way, yes.